# Check if a string is build out of the same letters as another string

Tags: java, string, compare

The topic explains my wish pretty well i think. So what i want to reach is:

```
madeOutOfSameLetters("aaasdf", "xyz") // false
madeOutOfSameLetters("aaasdf", "asdf") // false
madeOutOfSameLetters("aaasdf", "aaasdd") // false
madeOutOfSameLetters("aaasdf", "fdsaaa") // true
```

Is there a (combination of) method(s) I can use for, or do I need to do it by my own?

In second case I would count each letter of both strings, write it into arrays and compare them to each other. But that seems to be more complicated than it has to be to me. Any easier ideas?

Comment: can i ask why the second one is false?

Comment: you want the length of both strings to be same?

Comment: ...I didn't see that.

Comment: If the second string contained the same letters as the first yet the second had its letters scrambled (i.e. `"aaasdf","afadas"`) would this return true?

Comment: I presume if strings backwards are the same and vice versa then true

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use [`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) and [`Arrays.sort(char[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28char[]%29) and [`Arrays.equals(char[], char[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28char[],%20char[]%29). That is, something like,

```
public static boolean madeOutOfSameLetters(String a, String b) {
    if (a == null) {
        return b == null;
    } else if (b == null) {
        return false;
    }
    char[] left = a.toCharArray();
    char[] right = b.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(left);
    Arrays.sort(right);
    return Arrays.equals(left, right);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(madeOutOfSameLetters("aaasdf", "xyz")); // false
    System.out.println(madeOutOfSameLetters("aaasdf", "asdf")); // false
    System.out.println(madeOutOfSameLetters("aaasdf", "aaasdd")); // false
    System.out.println(madeOutOfSameLetters("aaasdf", "fdsaaa"));// true
}
```

Output is the requested

```
false
false
false
true
```

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - How on earth did you understand what the OP wanted ? :P

Answer (score 4):

An easier idea:

1. Sort the letters on each string `s1` and `s2`.
2. Remove duplicate letters from `s1` and `s2`.
3. Check if `s1` is equal to `s2`. If it is, then both strings are "made out of same letters". Otherwise, they don't.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, removing duplicate letters would also make "aaasdf" and "asdf" work. But without that (so only the sorting) it would work. Do you know an easy way of sorting a string? So make "yzxabc" turn to "abcxyz"? My idea would be translating every single letter to its ASCII value and build a new string out of it.

Comment: It beat my logic of using a char array, anyway :P

Comment: @Pablo, If the comments below the question are correct, then could you add in **1a.** Check if strings are same length?

Comment: Oh! I didn't know they were supposed to be made **exactly of the same letters** including letters count. If that's the case, just remove step #2 and you are done.

Comment: including letter count?

Comment: @jbutler483 no, that *will be necessary but not sufficient*. It would fail on the case `aabc` and `abbc`.

Comment: Sorry, i meant if they weren't the same when they first entered, then return false automatically - as they will not be the same length (example 2)