# How to get all the words with same characters from a JSON array of four letter words?

Tags: arrays, json, cpu-word

I have a JSON array with all the four letter words from which I pick a random word and present to the user in a jumbled form. But the problem is that sometimes there are more than one solution for the jumbled word.

For example: "tins","snit","nits" are three words with the same letters 't','i','n','s'.

How can I get the all the words that have the letters of the word that I picked in random from the JSON array?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding All Combinations of JavaScript array values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331092/finding-all-combinations-of-javascript-array-values) This show how to use multiple arrays but this may work for you too.

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25913143/923441

Basically you sort the strings' characters alphabetically and then test if the strings are equal to each other

Comment: Is the question *how to generate all the possible words* or *how to check that the word is valid*?

Comment: no it's about checking if other words in the array has same letter as the picked word.for example by random i pick a word "what" than it must check the array for words like "thaw" or "hawt".

Comment: thank you @a-steenbergen ! the comment helped,wasn't exactly what i was looking for,but i figured out from there.

Comment: I don't know if stackoverflow allows it but I eventually found the solution with the help of comments and made this android app. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.brainiacs.wordplay (it was my first android app)